# Laravel QueryBuilder...GroupBy and Count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I crawl my website and save crawl status code (200,301, etc..) and crawl depth (0,1,2,3.Etc..)
Each enter in my database/model contains : url, status_code, crawl_depth

I tried to get all differents status code for each crawl_depth level, for this I tried to build an array (or collection) from Eloquent or DB::query

```
An array where index is the crawl_depth
$array[crawl_depth] = [
            '200' => '114' //num of url with status code '200' in this crawl_depth
            '301' => '115' // num of 301
            etc...
         ]
```

I need to build the query, but I didn't find the good query, I've a piece of a solution but so far from what I try to get.

```php
$crawlDepth = DB::table('crawl_urls')
            ->where('project_id', '=', $this->project->id)
            ->select('crawl_depth', DB::raw('count(*) as UrlOnthisDepth'))
            ->groupBy('crawl_depth')
            ->get();
```

with this query, I get count url on each level :

```
 Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1445 ▼
  #items: array:6 [▼
    0 => {#1486 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 0
      +"UrlOnthisDepth": 1
    }
    1 => {#1447 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 1
      +"UrlOnthisDepth": 52
    }
    2 => {#1488 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 2
      +"UrlOnthisDepth": 215
    }
    3 => {#1490 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 3
      +"UrlOnthisDepth": 563
    }
    4 => {#1491 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 4
      +"UrlOnthisDepth": 341
    }
    5 => {#1492 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 5
      +"UrlOnthisDepth": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

With this other query :

```
$crawlDepth = DB::table('crawl_urls')
            ->where('project_id', '=', $this->project->id)
            ->select('crawl_depth', 'status_code')
            ->groupBy('crawl_depth', 'status_code')
            ->get();
```

I get this results, not so far, but I miss the number of url with each status code

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1368 ▼
  #items: array:11 [▼
    0 => {#1488 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 0
      +"status_code": 200
    }
    1 => {#1486 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 1
      +"status_code": 200
    }
    2 => {#1487 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 1
      +"status_code": 302
    }
    3 => {#1489 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 1
      +"status_code": 500
    }
    4 => {#1490 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 2
      +"status_code": 200
    }
    5 => {#1491 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 2
      +"status_code": 302
    }
    6 => {#1492 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 3
      +"status_code": 200
    }
    7 => {#1493 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 3
      +"status_code": 302
    }
    8 => {#1494 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 4
      +"status_code": 200
    }
    9 => {#1495 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 4
      +"status_code": 302
    }
    10 => {#1496 ▼
      +"crawl_depth": 5
      +"status_code": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting that specific output from an eloquent query will be difficult (if not impossible). You may be better off by just extracting the data and restructuring it after.

Using this query:

```
$crawlDepth = DB::table('crawl_urls')
            ->where('project_id', '=', $this->project->id)
            ->select('crawl_depth', 'status_code', DB::raw('count(*) as UrlOnthisDepth'))
            ->groupBy('crawl_depth', 'status_code')
            ->get();
```

You'll get a collection like `[[crawl_depth0, status_code0, count0], [crawl_depth1, status_code1, count1], ...]`. You can then restructure it by iterating the results (untested code, but you get the idea):

```
$structured = collect();
$crawlDepth->each(function($row) use ($structured) {
    $cd = $row->get('crawl_depth');
    if (! $structured->has($cd)) {
        $structured->put($cd, collect());
    }
    $structured->get($cd)->put($row->get('status_code'), $row->get('UrlOnthisDepth'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return DB::table('crawl_urls')
        ->groupBy(['crawl_depth', 'status_code'])
        ->get(['crawl_depth', 'status_code', DB::raw('count(*) as UrlOnthisDepth')])
        ->groupBy('crawl_depth')
        ->transform(function (Collection $value) {
            return $value->transform(function ($foo) {
                unset($foo->crawl_depth);

                return $foo;
            });
        });
```

for the following data set;

```
1,a,300,2
2,a,200,1
3,a,300,4
4,b,200,5
5,c,200,1
6,a,300,1
```

it will provide following json.

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "status_code": 200,
      "UrlOnthisDepth": 2
    },
    {
      "status_code": 300,
      "UrlOnthisDepth": 1
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "status_code": 300,
      "UrlOnthisDepth": 1
    }
  ],
  "4": [
    {
      "status_code": 300,
      "UrlOnthisDepth": 1
    }
  ],
  "5": [
    {
      "status_code": 200,
      "UrlOnthisDepth": 1
    }
  ]
}
```